# Efficient approach for fetching many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many

I have the following tables:

```
team:     identifier, name
fan:      identifier, name
team_fan: team_identifier, fan_identifier
```

In other words, there is a many-to-many relation between team and fan.

I want to fetch all teams for which a certain condition is met; and for each selected team, I want to fetch all its fans. So, in my application, I want to have the following data-structures:

```
Team A
     Fan F1
     Fan F2
Team B
     Fan F1
     Fan F3
Team C
     Fan F2
     Fan F3
     Fan F4
```

I already came up with the following solutions:

**[0] default, typical approach**

The default, typical approach is the inner join:

```
select     team.name, fan.name
from       team
inner join team_fan
on         team.identifier = team_fan.team_identifier
inner join fan
on         team_fan.fan_identifier = fan.identifier
where      ... (team conditions)
```

This provides all the required information to construct the data-structures as demonstrated above.

There a lot of teams and fans can belong to multiple teams. The query above might not be a good idea, because teams and fans are duplicated in the result. All these duplicates need to be transmitted over the wire.

In the alternatives below, I am doing the JOIN in the application. The alternatives below might be slower, but I don't know yet. I want to compare and learn from this.

**[1] very naive approach**

First, we select all teams:

```
select name from team where ...
```

Then, for each team with identifier X, we select its fans:

```
select name
from   fan
where  exists(select 1 from team_fan where team_identifier = X)
```

This is a bad solution, because the number of required queries is `1 + number of teams`. Also, a fan belonging to multiple teams is fetched multiple times. We can do better.

**[2] top-down approach**

First, we select all teams. While doing this, we also collect in an array all fans belonging to the team:

```
select  name, array(select identifier
                from   fan
                where  exists(select 1 from team_fan where fan.identifier = team_fan.fan_identifier and team.identifier = team_fan.team_identifier)) as fans
from  team
where ...
```

Then, in our application, we construct the union of all fan identifiers. Given this set of fan identifiers, we can select all fans:

```
select name from fan where identifier in(...)
```

Now, I have enough information to replicate the JOIN in my application and construct the data-structures as demonstrated above.

This seems like a better solution. The number of queries is always 2. Also, each team and each fan is only fetched once.

**[3] bottom-up approach**

I called the previous solution `top-down` because we are adding an array of children (fan) to the parent (team). In this approach, we do the inverse: we are adding an array of parents (team) to the child (fan).

So, first, let's just select all teams:

```
select name from team where ...
```

Next, in our application, we construct the union of all team identifiers. Given this set of team identifier, we can select all fans:

```
select name, array(select team_fan.team_identifier from team_fan where fan_identifier = fan.identifier and team_identifier in(...))
from   fan
where  exists(select 1 from team_fan where fan_identifier = fan.identifier and team_identifier in(...));
```

Now, I have enough information to replicate the JOIN in my application and construct the data-structures as demonstrated above.

This seems also like a valid solution. Also in this case, the number of queries is always 2. Also, each team and each fan is only fetched once.

**My question**

So, back to my question: I want to fetch all teams for which a certain condition is met; and for each selected team, I want to fetch all its fans.

Currently, I am unsure if approach 2 is better than approach 3 (or vice versa), or even, if there are better approaches for this. Any insights are welcome.

Comment: All your approaches seem more complicated than necessary.  Also, selecting * also seems unnecessary.  Have you considered simple inner joins?

Comment: @DanBracuk I am looking for alternatives for simple inner joins, to avoid duplicates of teams and fans in the output. The result becomes huge because of these duplicates. The alternatives might be slower, but I don't know yet. I want to compare and learn from this.

Comment: What is your expected output? I cannot see how to solve this withjout having either duplicte teams or fans? How are the results to be used?
If it is size you are worried about, then filter the teams, and get the filtered **team** table, **team_fan** table filtered on teams, and **fan** table filtered on the filtered team_fans table. Thus basically getting a full copy of your data filtered on teams. Then you application can replicate the join made in SQL to explode the data

Comment: In my application, I want a list of teams, and for each team, I want a sub-list of fans. That's my expected output. I don't have an expected output of one or more SQL queries. So this is not the typical `I want a query with output ABC` question.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion (`then filter the teams ....`), that's exactly what I did in these approaches. My question is: which is best? Are there better approaches?

Comment: I updated the question to add this information.

Comment: inner joins and DISTINCT seems to be the thing you want - let the database do the work it was designed to do

Comment: @Randy Where would `DISTINCT` help?

Comment: `In my application, I want a list of teams, and for each team, I want a sub-list of fans` :: in fact, what you want is a subset of the teams_fans table. That you want to aggregate the fans as *one_list_per_team* will not change the data your query needs to produce.

Comment: @joop I have no idea what you are `really` saying here... :( Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you should given an example of the kind of output you expect. (only a single list of fans, or one list of fans per team)

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully, it is clear now that I am not looking for a one specific, single query, but for an approach to read many-to-many relations.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple join

```
Select
    t.identitfier team_identifier
    ,t.name team_name
    ,f.identitfier fan_identifier
    ,f.name fan_name
From team t 
inner join team_fan tf 
on t.identifier=tf.team_identifier
/* and --(team condition can be put here) */
inner join fan f on tf.fan_identifier=f.identifier
/*where ... --(or team condition can be put here)*/
```

Comment: I am looking for alternatives for simple inner joins, to avoid duplicates of teams and fans in the output. The result becomes huge because of these duplicates. The alternatives might be slower, but I don't know yet. I want to compare and learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend modifying option 2 and removing the fan table altogether.

Assuming there are fewer teams than fans this approach will return fewer rows to your application and will likely be more efficient as the array function will not need to execute on as many rows as the alternative.

```
SELECT
    name, 
    array(
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            fan_identifier 
        FROM team_fan 
        WHERE team.identifier = team_fan.team_identifier
    ) as fans
FROM team
WHERE ...
```

Comment: I have no idea how this is an answer to the question. This selects fans. Should this be applied to approach 1 or approach 3?

Comment: Based on your question you are looking to get a list of fans based on criteria of teams.  Right?  This will do that for you.  I've just changed the where clause to point out where you would put your team search criteria.

Comment: So this returns a list of fans. How do I know which fan belongs to which team?

Comment: You can't with this query.  Although you say the inner join is the very naive approach, relational data models work best with inner joins.  In the edit of your post you say you are looking for
    Team A
         Fan F1
         Fan F2
    Team B
         Fan F1
         Fan F3

In table format that is expressed as 
Team A - Fan F1
Team A - Fan F2
Team B - Fan F1

etc... which is what you say you are not looking for.

are you trying to send your data in non-tabular format?  Or would you like to concatenate a string or send an XML object as a single column?

Comment: That's the data structures I need in the application. To create these data structures, I need to execute one or more queries. I listed 4 approaches.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  In that case, I think a version of approach 2 would work best vs approach 3 as the less efficient apply function will be run on a fewer number of rows if you use teams instead of fans as the table in the FROM clause.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, approach 2 is better because you expect that the number of teams will be smaller than the number of fans, which means that the `array(select ...)` will be executed fewer times (for each time) than the `array(select ...)` from approach 3 (for each fan)? If, for some odd reason, the number of teams is greater than the number of fans, then approach 3 would be better?

Comment: Yes.  Because we would expect the number of teams to be fewer than the number of fans, the apply operator will likely be more efficient and it will return fewer rows to your application.  If for some reason you had fewer fans than teams, then it is a sad state of affairs :) and yes, you'd want to swap that.

I also recommend removing the fan table altogether and simply using

select distinct fan_identifier from team_fan where team.identifier = team_fan.team_identifier as your select in the apply function.

Comment: These are some very good insights. I'll start to try it out and compare performance :). Unless some other ideas pop up, I will accept this answer in the next days. Thank you for your thoughts and ideas.